Problema con discord al enviar un archivo de audio con discord.js y ytdl-core
Tengo un pequeño error en este comando que estoy creando, el erro es que, si el video dura de 3 minutos o más, el audio se enviara múltiples veces.
He intentado crear banderas para que esto no suceda, pero tal parece que el problema puede ser de discord.js aunque no he encontrado nada relacionado con esto.
los logs que se generan son:

=> | Tachidito Bot está listo! | <=


=>|Tachidito_bot esta: Enviando audio...


=>|Tachidito_bot a: Error al enviar el audio
DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was aborted
at new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:53:5)
at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:395:18)
at Timeout.


(C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Escritorio\Tachidito_Bot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:680:47)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)


=>|Tachidito_bot a: Archivo eliminado


=>|Tachidito_bot a: Proceso terminado

los logs de que el tiempo de espera fue excedido se generan DESPUES DE QUE SE ENVIA EL PRIMER O SEGUNDO MENSAJE para que consecutivamente se envíe el mensaje de nuevo (unas 3 o 4 veces)
mi código:
// Dependencias que se requieren
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

// inicio de la función 
module.exports = {
  description: 'Descargar el audio de un video de youtube',
  run: async (message) => {
    const url = message.content.slice(2).split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    // Validar si el mensaje tiene un link
    if (!url) return message.channel.send('Debes proporcionar un link de youtube');
    // Validar si el link es valido
    if (!ytdl.validateURL(url)) return message.channel.send('Debes proporcionar un link valido');
    // obteniendo la información del video
    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
    // obteniendo el titulo del video y mandar un mensaje con el titulo, la duración y el autor
    message.channel.send(`Descargando ${info.videoDetails.title} - ${info.videoDetails.lengthSeconds} segundos - ${info.videoDetails.author.name}`);
    // Descargar el video en formato mp3 y guardarlo en la carpeta media
    message.channel.send(' Descargando...');
    const stream = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    // Guardar el archivo en la carpeta media 
    const filename = `./media/${info.videoDetails.title.replace(/\W+/g, '_')}.mp3`;
    // Crear un archivo de escritura
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    // Guardar el archivo en la carpeta media
    stream.pipe(writeStream);
    // Mandar un mensaje de que el archivo se ha guardado
    writeStream.on('finish', async () => {
      message.channel.send(` Archivo guardado como: ${filename}`);
      message.channel.send(' Enviando audio...');
      // Mandar un unico mensaje con el archivo adjunto
      try {
        console.log('=>|Tachidito_bot esta: Enviando audio...');
        const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(filename);
        await message.channel.send({ files: [attachment] });
        console.log('=>|Tachidito_bot a: Audio enviado!');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('=>|Tachidito_bot a: Error al enviar el audio');
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send(' Error al enviar el audio, contacta a un administrador para solucionar el problema');
      }
      // Eliminar el archivo de la carpeta media despues de enviarlo
      fs.unlink(filename, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('=>|Tachidito_bot a: Archivo eliminado');
        console.log('=>|Tachidito_bot a: Proceso terminado');
      });
    });
  }
};

